# When we use a for loop to create functions - is it a closure?

Tags: python, for-loop, closures, free-variable

I'm trying to get across the concept of closure in Python. I have seen many examples like that:

```
funcs = []
for n in range(1, 4):
    funcs.append(lambda x: x + n)

for f in funcs:
    print(f(1))
```

I get why the output is: `4 4 4`

But what I can't understand is why this is called a closure at all? Isn't closure supposed to be a nested function that has access to the variables of the enclosing function? While here we just modify a global varible `n` which equals 3 after the last cycle.

What is more, if you assign a variable for a function

```
a = funcs[1]
print(a.__closure__)
print(a.__code__.co_freevars)
```

It returnes

```
None
()
```

So tell me please, does the code above creates a closure or doesn't? Should I think of `n` as a free variable in closure or just a global variable?

Comment: You try to reason about an "enclosing function" when you didn't create any enclosing function. You're working on global variables. The content of `__closure__` and `__code__.co_freevars` will be different if you put your code into a proper function

Comment: A small note: you'd want to use functools.partial for the correct results, not a lambda. When you use a lambda, only the last valur of n (which is 3) is used, hence why you get 4 4 4 (3+1) instead of the expected 2 3 4

Comment: "But what I can't understand is why this is called a closure at all?" Because it isn't. Closure is a *nested* function where the inner function maintains access to the local variables of the outer function even after the outer function is closed.

Comment: I try because I always see similar examples when researching on closures. Maybe I should specify here: when we just use global variables inside a function - is it a closure? Or a closure is only when we have a function inside another function?

Comment: A function that is defined in the global scope is simply a function, even if it is an anonymous function (lambda). When you see an example of an alleged closure without outer function, you can safely assume that the outer function was omitted from the presented code and is implicitly there. Executing code in the global scope is bad practise anyway

Comment: You could also argue that a regular function is a closure whose only captured outer scope is the global scope.

Comment: See [link](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-closures/) for an explanation of how closures work and how they are implemented.

Comment: This link is exactly where I took this example. In the section "Python closures and for loop" you can find "use a lambda expression to create a closure". That still confusing, because there is no enclosing function

Comment: My interpretation is that the lambda code is a means of demonstrating when values are evaluated. I suppose the idea is something which seems closure-like in that values are intended to be retained (but aren't).